# Celery connection to Redis throwing "timed out" error only when delay method called from Django view

Tags: django, celery, azure-redis-cache, kombu

I am perplexed with this error and looking for some expert help. Here are the details -

- I am running a Django application with celery to schedule and execute tasks
- I use Azure Cache for Redis as the celery backend and broker
- Azure Redis has SSL port enabled and non-SSL port disabled
- I have configured SSL using URL scheme (`rediss://`) as well as celery config (`broker_use_ssl` and `redis_backend_use_ssl`)
- My Task is defined in one django app and the view is in another (though they are deployed together)
- Everything works also fine in my local setup, where I don't use SSL on redis
- My django server is running with gunicorn inside a docker container

Everything works just fine when celery-beat schedules a task and workers pick them up to execute. They both are able to communicate with Redis fine.

However, when I call a task from my django view directly, with delay function, I see a timeout error on connecting Redis.

Here is how I am calling the task (removed some boilerplate code for brevity):

```
from mydjangoapp import tasks

def MyViewFunction(request):
    tasks.MyTask.delay(param1, param2, param3)
```

Here is the error I see :

```
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Error while reading from <my-redis-server-url>:6380: ('timed out',)
```

Can someone please point out what happens differently when I call `task.delay()` from django view than celery workers?

Not sure if I missed any important detail. Please let me know and will update it in the Question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try connecting to redis first directly using https://github.com/redis/redis-py with ssl? You can debug better.

Comment: @LemonReddy Can you please explain a little more how this will help? Redis is definitely not an issue, since beat and workers are working just fine. And I am not using any custom code to connect redis (celery libs are doing this). Some more lights on what you are suggesting would help greatly.

Comment: Does your celery beat and django app use same celery configuration. And can you also share your configuration? It might be possible that configuration is different between celery beat and django app.

Comment: @LemonReddy I have single celery.py under the main django app where I load all the config from settings.py under CELERY namespace and use that across all the other apps. There are no separate beat and django app config. Can you please help explain what do you mean by config is different?